# List Multiple Values Using Laravel Model::lists()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to return to a list of categories (which are sortable on the view using JQuery UI) upon updating a record. Therefore I have a column in my database called "order" which keeps track of the order in which the categories should be displayed.

Because of this, I need to return not only the category's name and the ID, but also the value of the "order" column. Originally, my return statement in the controller looked like this:

```
return View::make('income-category.index')->with(array('categories'=> IncomeCategory::lists('income','id'), 'message'=>'updated'));
```

Of course, this worked fine before I needed to also return the order. Do I have to send through two lists() or is there a way to send through three columns? For example:

```
return View::make('income-category.index')->with(array('categories'=> IncomeCategory::lists('income','id','order'), 'message'=>'updated'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use the `orderBy()` method to get the result you want

`IncomeCategory::orderBy('order')->lists('income', 'id');`

If this doesn't work or you have a non-sequntial order, your best bet would be to write a function that creates the array you want.

Comment: Thanks! Now suppose I actually needed to use the values in the order column for some reason on the next page? I'm assuming that's where I would be best off just making my own function?

Comment: You could do it as a function, or you could pass over a couple variables. `array('categories' => IncomeCategory::orderBy('order')->lists('income', 'id'), 'order' => IncomeCategory::lists('id', 'order'));` or something similar. Then you have both of these arrays with a common id so you can do your sorting.

Comment: Right that was my initial plan but I wanted to avoid getting into multiple foreach loops and keep it as neat as possible. Thanks again.